# POST action taking JSON and returning JSON with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, json

I'm developing a web service in which I have resources of type A owning resources of type B.

I want to develop an API for getting stats about an A, but only considering a subset of its Bs.

So I'd have a route taking an A's ID, a collection of IDs of Bs, and returns the stats. I'd use it like the following:

```
POST /api/StatsAboutA/{aId}

JSON payload:
[1, 4, 12]
```

And it'd return something like that:

```
[
  {"key": ..., "value": ...},
  ...
]
```

Here is my controller:

```
class StatsAboutAController : ApiController
{
  // ...

  // POST api/StatsAboutA/{aId}
  [HttpPost]
  public Stats Post(long aId, IEnumerable<long> bIds)
  {
    A a = _aRepository.SelectById(aId);
    if (a == null)
    {
      throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }
    return _aRepository.CollectStats(a, bIds);
  }

  // ...

}
```

I can't manage to configure my router so that my controller matches my route.

Here is the error message I get:

```
{
    "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:51398/api/StatsAboutA/1'.",
    "messageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'StatsAboutA' that matches the request."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method signature to

```
public Stats Post(long aId, [FromBody]IEnumerable<long> bIds)
```

Because it is trying to get the bIds from the URI and that route is not defined.